# Using Jinja2 with Gulp

Tags: html, gulp, jinja2

I'm having a problem in using **Jinja2** templates with **Gulp**. I use Flask framework and my files structure has layout.html and index.html. When trying to run Gulp server I see something like:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% block title %} Home {% endblock %} {% block main %} {% endblock %}
```

...instead of a real page. Meaning that gulp doesn't know how to read jinja2 files (layout.html in this case). Is there a solution?

Comment: Correct, gulp is basically a task runner, it does not know anything about jinja2 or html or php or any other programming language. Unfortunately I don't use jinja2 but I do use nunjucks (which is a direct port of jinja2...and highly recommended). To convert my nunjucks templates to html, I and most others use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks-render  You may be able to find a similar package for jinja2? Or if you are just getting started, I would recommend checking out nunjucks, it's maintained by Mozilla.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am really only at the beginning level. I've checked nunjucks before when was looking for a solution for my problem. Could you tell me, why is nunjucks recommended? Does it have any else advantages compared to jinja2?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why, more than I can explain here unfortunately. The announcement of nunjucks has some good main points: http://jlongster.com/Introducing-Nunjucks,-a-Better-Javascript-Templating-System

Comment: Also -- jinja2 bills itself as a "templating language for Python". So it would seem that to use/compile jinja2 templates, you'll have to use python. I wouldn't even know how to implement jinja2 with node packages/gulp because of that. Nunjucks is javascript-based, which is why it works nicely with gulp. https://zellwk.com/blog/nunjucks-with-gulp/ and his ebook, though quite expensive, were very helpful learning nunjucks.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for those who struggle with this, there's a gulp plugin called [gulp-twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-twig).

#### Step 1

Install gulp using `npm install --save-dev gulp-twig`

#### Step 2

Define the task in your `gulpfile.js`:

```
const twig = require("gulp-twig");

function htmlTask() {
  return src("path/to/**/*.html")
    .pipe(twig())
    .pipe(dest("dist/"));
}
```

Change the `src` or `dest` paths as you wish.
You can also pass `data` to `twig()` and specify the key and values you want to send to every file (example in the [gulp-twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-twig) page).

#### Step 3

export the task like other ones

```
exports.default = series(
  // other tasks...
  htmlTask,
);
```

**All Done**

### Prettier

You may struggle with prettier messing up your twig and removing newlines between twig parts. In that case, first you have to run `npm install --save-dev prettier-plugin-twig-melody` then make a `.prettierrc.js` file in the root directory and paste this inside it:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["prettier-plugin-twig-melody"],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.html",
      options: {
        printWidth: 100 // Adjust this value as per your needs
        // Add any other Prettier options you want to customize
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

**NOTICE**: You have to replace `*.html` with `*.twig` or prettier will not work as before for html files. But since I don't know anything about Flask, I'll leave it like this in here.